# Is a composition of items a "composed item"?

Tags: adjectives

Let's say I have standard items. I now group them together to create a composition of items. Is it correct to speak of "a composed item"? Some dictionaries say it does, but most seem to give composed the meaning of "calm, relaxed item" rather than "a composition of"

Answer (score 3):

A better term would be a **[composite](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/composite?q=composite)** item

> made up of various parts or elements.
>    (especially of a constructional material) made up of recognizable constituents:
>   *a new composite material—a blend of plastic and ceramic resins*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct to speak of an item made of constituent parts as a composed item, though whether you use *composed* or *composite* will depend on context. You would never call a composed salad (salade composée) a composite salad, for instance. But then you wouldn't use composed lumber to build a deck. *Composed* does seem to convey the sense of things combined in an orderly way--like the salad, or a musical composition, or a person whose emotions are comfortably in check. I think that's where the meanings of *composed* overlap.